# How to set up VS 2013 to work with Tuples

Tags: c#, tuples, c#-7.0

I come from Python and I would like to work also in C# projects with Tuples.

Is it possible to work with the C#7.0 features in Visual Studio 2013?
If yes how?

I have the latest version of VS2013 v.12.0.40629.00 Update 5 and .Net v.4.7.02053.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can change some project or build files to build with the newer compilers but you won't get ide support, which means you'll probably be fighting with intellisense and code completion which doesn't understand the new syntax.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just upgrade to the newer version of Visual Studio and avoid all the pain? VS Community is likely even free for you to use.

Comment: I'd highly recommend creating classes (even if they are simple with two fields) instead of using Tuples... people used to scripting languages tend to like using them, but in C# they tend to cause more problems than they solve. For example it's much more readable to see someObject.InterestRate than someTuple.Item1 when maintaining the code. Please consider this carefully

Comment: @DavidG Yes, the money ;) My boss will not spend for update.

Comment: @GertR Do you have less than 5 devs in your team?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, can we use Community 2017 for internal use (Intranet)?

Comment: You can use VS Community for any dev work if you are 5 devs or less, have less than 250 computers in company or have less than US$1million revenue..

Comment: @Milney, You need to read up on the new tuple syntax in C# 7. `Item1` etc are a thing of the past: tuple elements can now have real names.